# Rails QueryCache enabled, but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, query-cache, dalli

We have a Rails 4.2 app running on an Oracle backend, with memcached/Dalli as the cache store.

QueryCache does not seem to be working for repeated SQL within the same request.   Per the documentation:

> Query caching is a Rails feature that caches the result set returned
>   by each query. If Rails encounters the same query again for that
>   request, it will use the cached result set as opposed to running the
>   query against the database again.

Configuration in application/production.rb sets the cache store to Dalli, and toggles query_cache to true within production:

```
application.rb: config.cache_store  = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211', { namespace: 'BASE', down_retry_delay: 120 }

environments/production.rb:  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Running memcached in verbose mode, I can see all the fetches and sets and misses from our explicit low level caching (ie Rails.cache.set), but no evidence of any query caching. (Though I'm not 100% sure if the query cache should reach memcached or if it's just held in memory for the duration of the request).  Given I can see other caching activity within memcached, I'm fairly sure the connection/setup between memcached and the rails is OK.

I believe it is not being cached for two reasons:

1. No selects with the production log (in debug mode) show the CACHE
   prefix - just identical SELECT's with ever-so-slightly differing XX.XXms timestamps; and,
2. Enabling
   database auditing with Oracle shows dozens of identical SELECTS per
   request (ie identical SELECT query conditions with the same case and same bind  parameters)

One suggestion I have seen is to look at the Middleware to confirm that QueryCache is present, which it seems to be:

```
dave@test:~/code/app1$ rake middleware
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware>
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
```

Another suggestion was to check (and set) `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache_enabled` explicitely.
I have put that in a before_filter for the method I'm currently trying to optimise, and it reports itself as being enabled, but still no caching:

```
  def enable_qcache
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.enable_query_cache!
     logger.error "IS CACHE ENABLED:  #{ ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache_enabled}"
  end

   production.log: IS CACHE ENABLED:  true
```

Here is an example of the identical selects within the same request from the log:

```
  Policy Load (12.2ms)  SELECT * FROM (SELECT  "POLICY".* FROM "POLICY" WHERE "POLICY"."POLICY_ID" = :a1  ORDER BY policy_original_number DESC, policy_id DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1  [["policy_id", 459723071]]
  Policy Load (11.5ms)  SELECT * FROM (SELECT  "POLICY".* FROM "POLICY" WHERE "POLICY"."POLICY_ID" = :a1  ORDER BY policy_original_number DESC, policy_id DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1  [["policy_id", 459723071]]
  Policy Load (9.0ms)   SELECT * FROM (SELECT  "POLICY".* FROM "POLICY" WHERE "POLICY"."POLICY_ID" = :a1  ORDER BY policy_original_number DESC, policy_id DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1  [["policy_id", 459723071]]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, query caching is implemented at the database connection level, 'config.cache_store` has nothing to do with it. Try switching your application to a supported adapter (eg. Postgres) to confirm whether your Oracle adapter is caching queries properly.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't even start the app up outside of oracle due to the rails front end being a retro-fit over a 20 year old legacy rails app - there are too many dependencies on the database code.    I have since found this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17921 which I think rules out Query Cache entirely for us - we bounce the connection around between multiple schemas on a per customer basis. (Cause of expensive oracle licensing costs)